# creating a stack of repeated keras models and bypassing part of the input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a keras model architecture in which a block of layers is repeated several times, with shared weights. For this I first create a base model, and then repeat this base model. This works fine:

```py
from tensorflow import keras

# build base model
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(32)(input)
out=keras.layers.Dense(4)(layer1)
base_model = keras.Model(input,out)
base_model.summary()
# repeat the model
n_repeat=4
for _ in range(n_repeat):
    out = base_model(out)

model = keras.Model(input, out)
model.summary()
```

Now I have a more special case, in which the input dimension is larger than the output dimension. The input data consists of a part that corresponds to the output, and a "fixed" part. In each repetition of the model, this fixed part should be the same. In the minimal example here this fixed part are the last 2 elements of the input vector. So it would be sufficient to create the input for the repeated model as a concatenation of the output and the last two elements of the input:

```py
# now with input shape 4 and output shape 2
# the input for the repeated model is the output of its predecessor
# and concatanated the last 2 values of the input
inshape=4
outshape=2
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(32)(input)
out=keras.layers.Dense(outshape)(layer1)
base_model = keras.Model(input,out)

n_repeat=1
for _ in range(n_repeat):
    out = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([out, input[:,outshape:]])
    out = base_model(out)

model = keras.Model(input, out)
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-190-38cf331e7c75>", line 17, in <module>
    model = keras.Model(input, out)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 111, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 78, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 201, in _init_graph_network
    '(thus holding past layer metadata). Found: ' + str(x))
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("model_21/dense_37/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32)
```

When replacing `out = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([out, input[:,outshape:]])`
with `out = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([out, out])` (just do include a concatenation that results in the right output shape), I do not get the error, so I guess it does not come from the Concatenate layer, but from the special case of concatenating part of the input. The error indicates that the final "out" is not the output of a Keras layer (and it indeed does not have the layer metadata). However, I do not know how to fix this, as it in fact should be the output of a layer.
I am using keras version '2.1.6-tf'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slicing of your `input` should be encapsulated in a `keras.layers.Lambda` layer.

Example below

```py
import keras

inshape = 4
outshape = 2

input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(32)(input)
out = keras.layers.Dense(outshape)(layer1)
base_model = keras.Model(input,out)

sliced_input = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda inp: inp[:, outshape:])(input)

n_repeat=2
for _ in range(n_repeat):
    out = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([out, sliced_input])
    out = base_model(out)

model = keras.Model(input, out)
model.summary()
```